# Android Edittext Completely Hide Password

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, passwords

It is typical to set the `inputType=textPassword` for fields where users would type in anything that is at risk, like...a password.  And when the user types it, each character they type is briefly flashed to let the user know what was actually entered and then turns into an asterisk so that casual observers (spies) have a lot more difficulty seeing what is typed.

Generally this works fine.

I have a specific case where for security reasons the character must NOT be flashed.  Instead I want to simply display the asterisk.

I could handle each tap individually via `setOnKeyListener()`, but it seems like this should be easy.  However I don't see any built-in solution.  Please tell me that I'm missing something.

Comment: Create your own [`TransformationMethod`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/TransformationMethod) that simply returns a `String` of the appropriate number of asterisks from `getTransformation()`, instead of the specialized `CharSequence` with timed spans that `PasswordTransformationMethod` does. You can apply it to your `EditText` with `setTransformationMethod()`.

Comment: @MikeM. this is pretty interesting, i've never heard of this before, might be worth writing as an answer ?

Comment: This example does what you want. It changes to . in the example but you can change it to * or whatever. It won't show the letters momentarily any more.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23110194/11582192

Comment: @a_local_nobody Meh, I don't really do that anymore. :-) Please feel free to post one, if you'd want to, but you might want to test it first. It's been a while since I've used that interface.

Comment: You can use before text changed event to store the character in array and then convert it to astrik. so, only astrik will be displayed and array will have your password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all those who commented, prodded, and pointed out excellent tips.  Using these valuable assists I was able to do something that was actually pretty easy and seems to work perfectly for this situation.

The trick is to override PasswordTransformationMethod and force your EditText to use this new one.  The original `charAt()` method uses Spannable that waits a second and half before hiding it.  By overriding that method your code can do something much simpler.

Here's an example of the custom class (in kotlin)

```
class ReallyHideMyPassword : PasswordTransformationMethod() {

    companion object {
        const val HIDE_CHAR = '*'
    }

    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence, view: View): CharSequence {
        return PasswordCharSequence(source)
    }

    inner class PasswordCharSequence (private val source: CharSequence) : CharSequence {

        override val length: Int
            get() = source.length

        override fun get(index: Int): Char = HIDE_CHAR

        override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence {
            return source.subSequence(startIndex, endIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

And to use this in your EditText:

```
    val et = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.my_password_edittext)
    et.transformationMethod = ReallyHideMyPassword();
```

Turns out that this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23110194/624814 (thanks Per.J!), but now you have it in kotlin.  It's so similar that this question will probably be closed as too similar.  But the wording of the question should help people find the answer more easily than the other post.

Comment: This solution does indeed seem to be necessary, as my initial suggestion of returning a `String` from a plain `TransformationMethod` has the same two big problems that the linked question does, though I'm not sure if that author knows why the answer fixes it. Firstly, though it's not _technically_ necessary (and is irrelevant to the current issue), extending `PasswordTransformationMethod` is definitely recommended, as there are several `instanceOf` checks for that specific class which affect internal behavior in `TextView` and `Editor`; e.g., wrt accessibility. Secondly, returning...

Comment: ...a disparate `String` does lead to an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, no matter if it's the right length or not. Though we might be setting plain text in typing, that's being wrapped internally in an `Editable`, and as the docs state "the returned text must mirror it dynamically instead of doing a one-time copy". This basically means that we need to wrap it in another `CharSequence` that can return the correct current length for an `Editable` that will change underneath it without notice. Anyhoo, just some additional info for this answer, since it's a little more explanatory than the other.

Comment: Btw, your `subSequence()` return isn't really right, yeah? (Though I'm not sure that it would be called at all here.) Lastly, just in case anybody wants to know, `PasswordTransformationMethod` uses `char DOT = '\u2022'` for its replacement character. That's all, I think. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for the comments and clarifications!  It always helps to see things from other people's point of view.  I haven't really tested the `subSequence()` function; did you find some errors with it?

Comment: No problem. That didn't work the way I had expected and suggested, and I had to find out why, so I thought I'd share in case anyone else wondered the same as I did. Anyhoo, that `subSequence()` is returning characters from the `source` `CharSequence`, which is what was passed into `getTransformation()`, which is what was typed into the `EditText`, not a sequence of asterisks, which is what you'd get if you used `get()` over the same range. I have no idea if that method would ever be called by `TextView` or `Editor`, or how the returned value might ever be used, though. Just a heads up, really

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything, I've struggled with this in the past and until now  *I've found no built-in solution*, I've used `addTextChangedListener` to do this and external libraries.

Disabling this setting does exactly what you asked, and it applies to every app but I guess you only can change this by code on a rooted phone.

I know this is no solution but it's a statement that this isn't available for developers and we have to make our own thing.

**EDIT:**
The comments offers great solutions but as you said, not built-in.

[image]

Comment: As you know, that's not what I was hoping for.  I've went ahead and done it the hard way (by using `setOnKeyListener()`).  I'll post my solution after I give others a chance.

Comment: I know, you asked if there a built-in solution. There is not, there are a lot of alternatives but you didn't ask for that.

Comment: Turns out the using `setOnKeyListener()` is _extremely_ awkward.  What a waste of time!  You have to account for all sorts of details that are just not worth it--you might as well write a custom EditText from scratch.  Sigh.